# Duplicate, then comment-out, a line in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, code-editor

With IntelliJ 2018, is there any keyboard shortcut to duplicate and disable lines of code?

If the caret is in a single line with no text selected, duplicate and disable that entire single line.

If text selected across multiple lines, duplicate and disable the entire lines of all selected text.

By "duplicate and disable", I mean:

1. Select the entire line(s).
2. Copy the text.
3. Comment-out that same text.
4. Paste below that text a copy.

I am using macOS, but it would be good to cover both PC & Mac shortcuts.

Some other Questions cover using `⌘c` to select and copy a line, and `⌘d` to select and duplicate a line. But I am looking for a multiple line solution, and a solution that comments out the original text after duplicating.

Comment: I'm not aware of any editor that has such functionality (it seems very narrow and specific to me), and IntelliJ IDEA definitely does not support this out of the box. However, you can fairly easily write a plugin to perform such an operation.

Comment: Select lines, ⌘(c,/) , → , ↵ , ⌘v . Are you looking for lesser number of key-strokes ?

Comment: @Gautam Thanks, but yes, I am looking for a shorter shortcut. It seems such a natural common thing to me to copy-paste-comment a block of code before experimenting with changes that I expected a feature or keyboard-shortcut.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) for this?

Comment: @Andrey, No I’ve not tried macros in IntelliJ. That might do it. Thanks.

Comment: This is a great idea.  I want it.  I am going to try and create a ticket with JetBrains.

Answer (score 2):

Create a macro in IDEA (Edit-> Macros-> Start Macro Recording)
that does the following

Action: EditorDuplicate
Action: EditorUp
Action: CommentByLineComment
Action: EditorLineStart

(obviously, you perform those actions from the keyboard yourself)

Give it a name something like 'DupAndComment'
You can then assign a shortcut (I used Alt-Shift-Home) to that macro by going to settings
Ctrl-Alt-S--> Keymap --> Macros (Right Click) --> Add Keyboard SHortcut.

Comment: That works fine on one line, thanks. Any idea on how to do the same on a multiple-lines selection ?